# Alternativa al AJAX sincrónico

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

Estoy haciendo una consulta AJAX para asignarle el valor a una variable que si o si tiene que estar declarada en otra función (estoy usando React). Tengo el siguiente código:

En una función A:

```
var datos = getAllProfessionals();
```

En getAllProfessionals():

```
function getAllProfessionals() {
    var jsonResponse;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: urlAjaxGetAllProfessionals, // Defined at HTML file
        async: false
    }).done(function(response) {
        jsonResponse = response;
    });
    return jsonResponse;
},
```

Me vi obligado a poner `Async: false` porque sin esos datos no hay nada que mostrar en la página, y ademas si o si tiene que almacenarse en datos. Pero no puedo hacer

```
...
}).done(function(response) {
        return response;
});
```

Y si dejo la variable fuera de la función $.ajax() se pierde el valor porque es asincrónico.

¿Que alternativas tengo para evitar poner el `async: false` y recibir la respuesta sin problemas?

Comment: Podrías considerar usar un state-manager como [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) o [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) que te ayudaría bastante en ese tipo de problemas

Comment: Gracias por responder! Mas tarde leeré un poco al respecto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta que los componentes de React funcionan como maquinas de estado, la Data de un componente en React siempre proviene ya sea del state o del props (properties), cuando mutas el state o el props el componente React automaticamente reacciona a estos cambios y vuelve a renderizar haciendo los cálculos necesarios para modificar la vista realizando los menores cambios posibles en el DOM. tu solución rompe todo este concepto y no estas utilizando React para lo que fue creado ya que no estas mutando el estado dependiendo de la respuesta del servidor y no utilizas el componente React para hacer las actualizaciones en la vista.

Fíjate en la siguiente implementación (ES6)

```
import React from 'react'
import update from 'react-addons-update'
import superagent from 'superagent'

export default class ProfesionalsListComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            profesionalList:    [],   // La lista de profesionales
            errorMensaje:       null, // Si hay un error
            estaCargando:       false // Si estoy haciendo la peticion
        }
    }

    componentWillMountMount() {
        let self = this;

        this.setState(update(
            this.state,
            {
                estaCargando: {$set: true}
            }
        ));

        superagent.get(urlDelEndpoint)
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .end(function(error, response){
                if(error) {
                    self.setState(update(
                        self.state,
                        {
                            error: {$set: 'Error al recuperar listado de profesionales'},
                            profesionalList: {$set: []},
                            estaCargando: {$set: false}
                        }
                    ));
                } else {
                    let data = response.body;
                    this.setState(update(
                        self.state,
                        {
                            error: {$set: null},
                            profesionalList: {$set: data},
                            estaCargando: {$set: false}
                        }
                    ));
                }
            });
    }

    render() {
        let contenido = null;

        if(this.state.errorMensaje) {
            contenido = (
                <div>
                    <h2>Hubo un problema!</h2>
                    <span>{this.state.errorMensaje}</span>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            let profesionalesItems = [];
            _.each(this.state.profesionalList, function(profesional){
                profesionalesItems.push(
                    <li>{profesional.nombre} {profesional.apellido}</li>
                )
            });

            contenido = (
                <ul>
                    { profesionalesItems }
                </ul>
            )
        }

        let cargando = null;

        if(this.state.estaCargando) {
            cargando = (
                <div>
                    <span>Cargando la informacion, espere por favor... </span>
                </div>
            )
        }

        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Listado de profesionales</h1>
                { cargando }
                { contenido }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

La petición ajax se realiza al momento de montar el componente, el componente decide que contenido renderizar dependiendo del estado, tu solamente mutas el estado y la vista reaccionara acorde.

Comment: Excelente respuesta! Gracias por sacarme de la ignorancia completa! Ahora tengo que ver como adaptarlo a mi ambiente, ya que no estoy usando node.js y no encuentro manera de importarlo

Comment: @Genarito Si no usas Node.js entonces solamente debes pasarlo a notación ES5, la librería superagent la puedes reemplazar por una simple llamada ajax usando jQuery $.ajax(...) y en lugar de usar lodash utiliza la función .each de jQuery, en ES6 la palabra reservada 'let' sirve para declarar variables locales, eso lo puedes remplazar por un simple 'var'.

Comment: Te pasaste! Ya estaba armando una pregunta destinada a este nuevo problema! Muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes realizar es llamar a una función cuando la información ha sido recibida (función callback). Para ello puedes poner el atributo `success` con el nombre de la función a la que quieres pasarle los datos en tu llamada de ajax y cuando la información haya sido recibida llamará a esa función pasándole como parámetros la información que haya sido recibida.

Quedaría algo así:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: urlAjaxGetAllProfessionals, // Defined at HTML file
    async: false,
    success: reciboParametros
})

function reciboParametros(parametros) {
    //Aquí iría el código que trabajara con los parámetros recibidos
}
```

Comment: Claro, el tema es que React JS utiliza un método llamado componentDidMount() que se llama automáticamente, y ahí es donde se declaran las variables que necesito, entonces no voy a poder ponerlo en el success

Comment: @Genarito La verdad que desconozco como funciona React JS pero entiendo que podrás llamar a la función una vez recibidos los datos.

Comment: Claro, puedo llamar a la función, pero React lo hace implícitamente. Cuando lo haga, si todavía mi AJAX no dio respuesta entonces me arrojaría error porque estaría intentando utilizar información que todavía no tiene

Comment: @Genarito Entonces entiendo que le podrás poner dentro de dicha función una condición. Si los parámetros son nulos, entonces que no haga nada y si no lo son, que inicialice los datos. De esta manera te asegurarás que no te produce un error.

Comment: Voy a intentar! Mil gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder