# ¿Como puedo usar una petición ajax async false si requiero que sea sincrona?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una peticion ajax que realizo para cargar un array, existe la posibilidad de no usar `async: false`
He buscado distintas soluciones a ello, pero la verdad, no las entiendo.

Código de la petición ajax.

```
function ObtenerTodoMenu() {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'post',
        url: 'tablero/menu',
        data: {
            '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            'id_perfiles': 
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (!data) {
                alert(data);
                return;
            }
            todoMenus = data.menu;
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(jQuery.parseJSON(request.responseText).Message);
        }
    });
}
```

Acá algunas preguntas que he visto que han realizado con dudas similares a las mias:
En español:
[Alternativa al AJAX sincrónico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39946/alternativa-al-ajax-sincr%C3%B3nico)

En ingles:

1- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re

2- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31309748/is-there-an-alternative-to-asyncfalse-in-jquery

Y esta fue la que mas ruido me causo, en la edición de la respuesta que el usuario aprobo como respuesta valida dice:

> Updating this answer in 2016 with an option that uses promises. Here's how you run the requests in series:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090764/alternative-to-async-false-ajax/22091143#22091143

**Actualización 1:**
Lo intento hacer con las `promesas` y no resuelve mi problema. Mi código:

```
    function ObtenerTodoMenu() {
        $.when($.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'tablero/menu',
            data: {
                'id_perfiles': 
            }
        })).done(function( data ) {
            console.debug(data)
            if (!data) {
                alert(data);
                return;
            }
            todoMenus = data.menu;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Respuesta corta**: La única manera es usar `async: false`.

**Respuesta larga**: Javascript es asíncrono por diseño. Esto significa que la manera natural de hacer una petición al servidor es de manera asíncrona, es decir, sin usar la opción `async: false`. ¿Qué mecanismos tengo entonces para saber el resultado? Puedes usar callbacks como los que hay en tu código de ejemplo (`success`, `error`) o otros como `always`,  ... Tu código debe estar diseñado para soportar información cargada de manera asíncrona ya que más pronto o más tarde lo vas a necesitar.

También añado que `async: false` lanza un warning en la consola en muchos navegadores modernos, ya que bloquea el hilo de ejecución y no permite la interacción del usuario con la página, por lo que funciona pero no se recomienda hacer uso.

Otro punto que mencionas son las promesas. No son más que una abstracción en la que se mantiene el estado del resultado, sabiendo si ya ha sido ejecutado el método o aún no. Con `jQuery.ajax` se puede hacer uso de promesas. Este sería un ejemplo.

```
$.when($.ajax("storage")).then(function(data, status, xhr) {
    // Lógica de respuesta aquí.
});
```

Ver: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: pero ninguno de los 3 (success, error y always) me sirven, no obtengo el valor del ajax.

Comment: Échale un ojo a las herramientas de Chrome y apoyate en `console.log(arguments)` para ver lo que recibes en `success`. Si la petición al servidor es correcta, deberías recibir como primer argumento el resultado de la petición. Existen otras funciones similares como `done` o `then`, prueba por si es la versión de jQuery aunque no debería.

Comment: en la consola obtengo el resultado pero obtengo ese resultado despues que se cargue todo, y necesito que el resultado lo arroja cuando ejecuto el ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo solucione declarando una variable antes de la llamada Ajax y haciendo el retorno

```
function ObtenerTodoMenu() {
    *let todoMenus;*
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'post',
        url: 'tablero/menu',
        data: {
            '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            'id_perfiles': 
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (!data) {
                alert(data);
                return;
            }
            todoMenus = data.menu;
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(jQuery.parseJSON(request.responseText).Message);
        }
    });
    *return todoMenus;*
}
```